# Why have a resistor in the secondary winding of a transformer?

Tags: electromagnetism

In a (ideal) transformer, the secondary winding is usually connected to a resistor. Why not connect the resistor to the primary winding? Why have a resistor at all?

Comment: Resistor in an ideal transformer model? That's strange. Do you have an example?

Comment: Let's say there is no resistor in an ideal transformer, then. Wouldn't the voltage drop be 0 due to Ohm's Law? Also, the picture in the textbook I'm using ("Physics for Scientists and Engineers") discusses an ideal transformer with a resistor connected to the secondary winding - Page 1015 - 1016, http://powerunit-ju.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Physics-Textbook-9th-E-GearTeam-ilovepdf-compressed.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pedagogical purpose of a resistor connected to the transformer secondary is to elucidate the voltage and current transfer properties of the transformer from primary to secondary. Without the resistor connected to the secondary, no current flows (ideally).

Note that your textbook is assuming infinite magnetizing inductance, so no amount of voltage can cause a current to flow in the primary without a load on the secondary.

Comment: So let's say, then, a primary winding in an ideal transformer has a voltage of 50 V, and the current is 25 A - by Ohm's law, the resistance is 2 Ohms. Where is this resistance coming from?

Comment: @JeanPierre It's the transformed resistance of the resistor on the secondary. If the transformer has 1:1 turns ratio, a 2Ω resistor connected to the secondary would produce this effect. If it's 1:2, an 8Ω resistor would produce this effect. This ignores the magnetizing current, which may be substantial in a real transformer, and does not obey Ohm's law.